# How to find the nearest prime number?

Tags: c++

The goal of this method is to find the nearest prime number less than the value passed. Any value less than 3 is undefined behavior so I just return -1. The issue lies when I pass in values 5, 20, 100, and 1, this is the output:

```
Passed in 5 Expected 3: 5
Passed in 20 Expected 19: 19
Passed in 100 Expected 97: 97
Passed in 1 Expected -1: -1
```

Here is the method:

```
int Hash::nearestPrime(int num){
        if(num <= 3){
                return -1;
        }
        for(int i = 2; i < num; i++){
                if(num == 3){
                        return 3;
                }
                if(num % i == 0 && num != i){
                        num--;
                        i = 2;
                }
        }
        return num;
}
```

Comment: Can you tell us the logic for the inside if statement?. It would be very helpful for us to understand your code. Thanks

Comment: Your problem seems to be that you are returning the nearest prime *less than or equal* to the number passed. Just substract one from `num` at the beginning to get the nearest prime *less than* the number passed.

Comment: Correct the first `if` to `num<3`, that's ambiguous.

Comment: `2`, on the other hand, is the oddest prime there is. Your check for `<= 3` is incorrect.

Answer (score 0):

You could loop and decrement until the next one is found, by having a function determine if a value is prime.

```
#include <iostream>

int prime (int n)
{
  int i;
  for (i = 2; i < n; i++)
    if (n % i == 0) return 0;
  return 1;
}

int run (unsigned int n)
{
  while (!prime (--n));
  return n;
}

int main ()
{
  std::cout << run (3);
  return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Your method is right but with simple mistake.

Assign `i = 1` instead of `i = 2` inside the `if` condition. Because if you assign 2 then for `i++` next checking value will start from **3**. But you need to check it from **2**.

```
int Hash::nearestPrime(int num){
        if(num <= 3){
                return -1;
        }
        for(int i = 2; i < num; i++){
                if(num == 3){
                        return 3;
                }
                if(num % i == 0 && num != i){
                        num--;
                        // mistake in this line
                        i = 1;
                }
        }
        return num;
}
```

Comment: That is not required. If a number has a prime factor of `2` with multiplicity `2` or larger, OP catches this by testing the case `i=4`. If a number has a prime factor of `2` with multiplicity `1`, then either it is `2` (which OP is excluding) or it has another prime factor unequal `2` which OP also catches.